# Safe to uninstall CUPS?

Tags: cups

I'm working with an unix installation with an extremely small amount of disk space. I want to uninstall CUPS since this system is never going to need to print.

Is it safe to uninstall this service? I don't want to proceed if anything depends on CUPS being installed.

Comment: Most distros (you haven't included what your is, which is not that helpful) will print a list of all of the packages to be uninstalled if you do a `$pkgmngr --recursive uninstall`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, If you don't need to print, you can safely uninstall CUPS.

CUPS has no use other than for printing.

By getting rid of CUPS, you might be able to "free up" further dependencies (i.e. libavahi)